# Optional right column in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have the following:

```css
.container {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;        
    height: 150px;        
    margin: 10px;
}
.main {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;        
}
.right-content {
    background: lightcoral;
    margin-left: 16px;        
    width: 250px;
}
.topb {
    border-top: 2px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="main topb">This is the <b>main</b> content</div>
 <div class="right">
  <!-- -->
  <div class="right-content topb">Optional content</div>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Conditions are the following:

1) `main` and `right` are always in the same row;
  2) if there is no (dynamic) div `right-content`, `main` will take all the width (100%);
  3) there is a 16px left-margin between `main` and `right-content`(if any);

4*) the page should display properly from IE 9...

With `display:flex` it could be a great deal, but is not supported in IE9 (compatibility view may pass, but not in real IE9)... Please suggest how to make this code compatible with this version of the "rebel" ( browser.

Comment: Try to achieve with JS, first check the class if it is present than adjust the width accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried setting your `.right-content` to have a `max-width` instead?

Comment: @jbutler483 why set a max-width for the right-content?, there is no restrictions on that

Comment: @serhio: that should sort out condition 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add some jquery to achieve this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(".right-content").text().length > 0) {
     $('.right').show();
   } else{
     $('.right').hide();  
   }
```

here is the updated **[fiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/bxtzz42k/)**

hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: ...hmm... interesting... perhaps use `html()` instead of `.text` if the content is an `img`by eg.